# Android - ImageView flickering by changing the Image (Bitmap) on it

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have got a Image (Bitmap) on a ImageView, without flickering. When I change something with `setPixel(x, y, COLOR_VALUE)`, so some Pixels are changed on the ImageView, it begins to flicker, where I changed the Pixels.

```
public class Drawer extends ImageView {

private Bitmap someBitmap;

public void doSomeDrawing() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 2) {
        someBitmap.setPixel(x, y, COLOR_VALUE);
    }
    setOnDraw();
}

public void setOnDraw() {
   this.setImageBitmap(someBitmap);
}
```

Comment: You should inlne setOnDraw. It has no value and doesn't respect setter's conventions (having a parameter).

Comment: yea, but that shouldn't solve the problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a copy of your bitmap and draw on it. Then recycle your old bitmap.

The problem here might also be that setting the pixel takes time and if you do this on the UI Thread, it will slow down your app and may cause flickering too. How much time does `doSomething` take ?

Comment: tried your first guess, didn't work. it does take some milliseconds, i guess 100-200 ms. Aren't there any mechanisms to lock the screen until it is finished with the calculation?

Comment: 100-200ms? That's A LOT. You should look into a SurfaceView, where you can compute your graphics on a separate thread and draw on the canvas just when you really have everything done.